# Can/Should I create instances of a UserControl in my viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

Question regarding UserControls and MVVM. I have my wpf app with a main View/ViewModel. The viewmodel has a ObservableCollection of my usercontrol(s)  that a listbox is bound to. The UserControl instances are added to the collection at run time based on events.

My question is if it's within the MVVM pattern to create the usercontrol objects from my main viewmodel? Example below in the onSomeEvent method is the code I'm unsure of, if this is where I should handle it? This doesn't feel right to me, but I'm still wrapping my mind around mvvm. Should I be adding the user control viewmodel here instead? Thanks for any guidance.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
{
    get { return myList; }
    set
    {
        myList = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MyList");
    }
}

public void onSomeEvent(string someData1, string someData2)
    {
        this.MyList.Add(new Views.MyUserControl(someData1, someData2));
    }
```

---

Ok, I mocked up some code based on feedback from BradleyDotNET and dymanoid as I wrap my mind around it. Pasting it here to see if I'm on the right track.

I modified the listbox in my mainview xaml to add a template:

```
<ListBox Name="lbMain" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test1}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test2}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I then created a simple class like this to populate a few fields.

```
public class MyData
{
    public MyData(string test1, string test2)
    {
        this.Test1 = test1;
        this.Test2 = test2;
    }
    private string test1;
    public string Test1
    {
        get
        {
            return test1;
        }
        set
        {
            test1 = value;
        }
    }

    private string test2;
    public string Test2
    {
        get
        {
            return test2;
        }
        set
        {
            test2 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my mainviewmodel I did this:

```
public void onSomeEvent(string someData1, string someData2)
    {
        this.MyList.Add(new MyData(someData1, someData2));
    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using templates?

Comment: My usercontrol is very simple now, but I do plan to eventually add some additional functionality allowing them to right click and get a menu with some choices pertaining to the data they selected. With this additional information do you still recommend a template? I ask because I am new to WPF and working my way through it. I do understand how to create a simple template in my listbox if I'm not concerned about adding additional functionality.

Comment: Yes, a template is *always* a good choice (even, **the** choice) if you are displaying items in a custom way inside a collection control (like `ListBox`)

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. I added to my original question to see if i'm on the right track.

Comment: Yep, that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your viewmodel should not create any `UserControl` instances, because they are views. Furthermore, your main viewmodel shouldn't contain any collections of any views. As @BradleyDotNET mentioned, `DataTemplate` is the right way for it.

You should change your main viewmodel collection. It shouldn't contain any `UserControl`s (views), but rather their viewmodels. Assuming that you have defined `DataTemplate`s for your sub-viewmodels in XAML, you will get your views automagically created by WPF.

This could look like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type local:UserControlViewModel}">
    <local:UserControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

With this approach, WPF sets the `DataContext` property value to the sub-viewmodel instance automatically, so you can easily define your bindings in that `UserControl`.